# Grid arrange in ggplot2 and fix ylabs for variable name

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm plotting all variables using ggplot2, with y-axis labels being the variable name. Then I'm arranging ggplot plots on a grid.

The resultant final plot has all the smaller plots having the final plot object getting replicated. Also I would like y-axis labels to be properly named.

Below is the code I've used for this purpose.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

data(iris)
plots = list()
for(i in 1:4){
  grf = qplot(x = 1:nrow(iris), y = iris[ ,i], 
              color = iris$Species, ylabs = colnames(iris)[i])
  plots = c(plots, list(grf))
}

do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

I humbly bow down in the corner, eagerly awaiting the response of a community far wiser than I.

Edit: Forgot to mention that I need the plots in a list for saving using `ggsave`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for...
Notice that you have to use the aes_string() function to get the charts to show properly

```
plots = list()
cols_to_plot <- colnames(iris)

for(i in 1:4){

  grf = ggplot(data = iris, aes_string(x = "1:nrow(iris)", y = cols_to_plot[i], color = "Species")) + 
    geom_point() +
    ylab(colnames(iris)[i])
  plots = c(plots, list(grf))
}    
do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

produces the following:

[image]

GGplot2 has some really great functionality (`facet_wrap`) for doing some of the same things you seem to be trying.  You need to have data arranged correctly to capitalize with on it (think "long & skinny data").

The `tidyr` does a great job of shaping data in a way that can be accepted easily by `ggplot2` and `ggvis` packages.

here is what it shows...

[image: grid_thingy]

```
require(ggplot2)
require(tidyr) # to reshape the data
require(dplyr) # to add the column of rownumbers.  not really necessary at all

iris %>% 
  mutate(rowNum = 1:nrow(.)) %>% #add the column of row numbers
  gather(Measure, Value, -(Species:rowNum)) %>% #from tidyr package - this is what makes it long.  Read the help on `gather` and `spread`
  ggplot(aes(x = rowNum, y = Value, group = Species, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Measure, nrow = 2) # the nice n' easy part.  Automatically plops it in your four separate charts based on the "Measure" variable (which was created when I made the data "long" instead of "wide").
```

Comment: Another nice thing about the second method is you have one file, ready for ggsave().

Comment: Oh just so perfect! The 2nd method is fine for small number of covariates. Because the dataset has 30k rows and 120 variables to plot, the graphics didn't really work out tiling so many graphs, each having so many datapoints. Nonetheless, both the method have their place to fill. Thanks @colemand77 for taking time and patience to answer this.

Comment: Ah, sorry I'll do that asap.